# Unable to Load Image on iPhone Simulator from Resource/Image Directory .NET MAUI (VS on MAC)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, visual-studio-code, maui

I recently began learning .NET MAUI, so please accept my apologies if the question appears basic.

This is AppShell.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Shell
    x:Class="Walmo_e_wallet_u.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Walmo_e_wallet_u"
    xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Walmo_e_wallet_u.Pages"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled">

    <TabBar>
        <Tab Title="Home">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:HomePage}" />
        </Tab>
        <Tab Title="Chart">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:ChartPage}" />
        </Tab>
        <Tab Title="QR">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:QrPage}" />
        </Tab>
        <Tab Title="Notification">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:NotificationPage}" />
        </Tab>
        <Tab Title="Wallet">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:WalletPage}" />
        </Tab>
    </TabBar>
</Shell>
```

And these are the images I dragged and dropped inside of the image folder:

[image]

Now I am trying to simply load them as the tab icon:

```
<TabBar>
    <Tab Title="Home" Icon="home.png">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:HomePage}" />
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title="Chart" Icon="chart.png">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:ChartPage}" />
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title="QR" Icon="qr.png">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:QrPage}" />
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title="Notification" Icon="notification.png">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:NotificationPage}" />
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title="Wallet" Icon="wallet.png">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:WalletPage}" />
    </Tab>
</TabBar>
```

I have placed the images in my image folder, but when I build the simulator, the screen goes black, and it remains stuck with no error message. If I remove the image from the tabbar code, the application loads successfully. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the missing part. I have to select all image as MauiImage. To do that:

1. Select one image, right-click, and choose "Build Action" from the context menu. From the list, select MauiImage.
2. Repeat this process for all image files in your project.
3. Build and Run the project

By setting the "Build Action" to MauiImage, you ensure that the images are processed correctly by .NET MAUI.

Comment: 1. Yes, you need to set the build action to `MauiImage` in your project. 2. You can check [Accept Your Own Answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) as it's helpful to others facing the same problem.

Comment: I am waiting for its acceptance since it takes a specific amount of time to accept one's own answer. It says, 'You can accept your own answer tomorrow.

Comment: @MingJie-MSFT Sorry for late reply. Yes, I accepted the answer. Thanks!